# Import notation from module signature in implementing module

Tags: coq

How can I make the notations defined in `Category` available in `HomCategory`?

```
Module Type Category.

  Parameter Object : Type.
  Parameter Arrow : Object -> Object -> Type.

  Infix "~>" := Arrow (at level 25) : category_scope.
  Open Scope category_scope.
  Delimit Scope category_scope with category.
  Bind Scope category_scope with Object Arrow.

  Variable id : forall a : Object, a ~> a.
  ...
End Category.

Module HomCategory <: Category.

  Definition Object := Type.
  Definition Arrow(a b : Object) := a -> b.

  Print Scope category_scope. (* Error: Scope category_scope is not declared. *)
  ...
End HomCategory.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid there is not really a way of doing this. The status of modules in Coq is weird, meaning that the only connection between a `Module Type` and something with that type is that Coq checks that the definitions are compatible with the signature. The `Arrow` declaration inside the module isn't really a first-class entity. Hence, there shouldn't be a way of making the connection between the notation defined in your signature and your implementation. There are two alternatives that come to my mind:

- Redeclare your notations every time you want to use them for something new.
- Do not use modules for ad-hoc polymorphism. With canonical structures or type classes, polymorphic operations do have a first-class status in the theory, making it easier to define such generic notations. Have a look for instance at the definition of the `==` notation for `eqtype`s in ssreflect: http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/~jenkins/current/eqtype.html.